# About modal pop control to the ajax control tool kit

Tags: c#, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

First of all hi too member 
now my 1st talk i had one ajax control tool kit tht doesnt work on the vs 2008 
so please help me for tht and 
other problem I had make one modal pop code for the site but it nt working properly 
mean when I click on the button it will only display Loader image but it did nt display tht page or div tag which cover the whole page with black color 
so i need that back ground color div tag

Some please help me 
I am badly stuck with this problem

in advance thank you

Comment: Can you please use punctuation and correct all the misspellings?  I am trying to decipher here.....You can display the ModalDialog but it doesn't "color" the background, therefore not making it Modal?

Answer (score 0):

If I have deciphered your post correctly, you can show the ModalDialog but it doesn't "color" the rest of the page, therefore making the popup non-Modal?

If this is the case, then you need set the `BackgroundCssClass` attribute of the `ModalPopupExtender` to a valid CSS class.

I normally use this...

```
 .ModalBackground
 {
      background-color:Gray;

      filter:alpha(opacity=50);
      -moz-opacity:0.5;
      -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
       opacity: 0.5;
 }

 <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="ModalBackground" [... the rest of the attributes....] />
```